# NameError: name 'AUTH' is not defined

Tags: docker-compose, dock, django-3.2

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager, PermissionsMixin
    
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['name',]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

When i run makemigrations, got this error:

```
File "/app/core/settings.py", line 133, in <module>
    AUTH
NameError: name 'AUTH' is not defined
```

In end of settings.py file i have added:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.User'
```

Comment: Remove `AUTH` from line 133 of `settings.py`

Comment: I do not have "AUTH" in line 133. There is "AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.User'" in line 133

Answer (score 0):

My container was stoped. I restart container and run `python manage.py makemigrations` again and error go away.